# Why does my HTML webpage show raw code sometimes

Tags: html, css, laravel

I encounter this problem sometimes when the back button is pressed. My webpage no longer displays the UI rather it breaks into raw HTML code. It gets fine on refreshing the page.

**EDIT**
It happens on live website as well at times. Though the screenshot is taken from google chrome running on local server. I haven't tried running this on another browser till now.

**snapshot**

[image]

What can be the possible reason behind that?

Comment: Please provide more info: server, browser, etc. Is this available online?

Comment: updated the question @ChrisTapay

Comment: it looks like a JSON being printed. Perhaps of lack of proper handling of navigation?

Comment: If there were a lack of proper handling of navigation, it would have appeared everytime but it does not appear always. Just sometimes. But it doesn't look good on my live site for users to encounter a crash like that. I'm even not getting a starting point of the problem. @ChrisTapay